# Access R Shiny selectizeInput Labels

Tags: r, shiny

How can I access the Label of the selected item of a selectizeInput control in shiny from R?

In the below example, if the user clicks on DM Ask, I would like to retrieve the value DM Ask, not DM_ask

```
output$group_quote_type_holder <- renderUI({
quote_type_names <- c("Bid Price", "Ask Price", "DM Bid","DM Ask")
quote_type_sql <- c("price_bid","price_ask","DM_bid","DM_ask")
names(quote_type_sql) <- quote_type_names
quote_type_named_list <- quote_type_sql
selectizeInput("group_quote_type",
             label = "Select a type:",
             choices = quote_type_named_list,
             selected = "DM_ask")
})# end renderUI
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value for `choices` in `selectizeInput` is a named list, the names are display to the user and values corresponding are returned in the server.

If you want to display "DM Ask" and return "DM Ask", just use your vector `quote_type_names`, e.g. :

```
selectizeInput(
  inputId = "group_quote_type",
  label = "Select a type:",
  choices = c("Bid Price", "Ask Price", "DM Bid", "DM Ask"),
  selected = "DM Ask"
)
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't understand. I assume `quote_type_named_list` don't exit in globaenv and it just define in `renderUI`, so something like this ?

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput(outputId = "group_quote_type_holder"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  quote_type_named_reac <- reactiveValues(x = NULL)

  output$group_quote_type_holder <- renderUI({
    quote_type_names <- c("Bid Price", "Ask Price", "DM Bid","DM Ask")
    quote_type_sql <- c("price_bid","price_ask","DM_bid","DM_ask")
    names(quote_type_sql) <- quote_type_names
    quote_type_named_list <- quote_type_sql

    quote_type_named_reac$x <- quote_type_named_list

    selectizeInput(inputId = "group_quote_type",
                   label = "Select a type:",
                   choices = quote_type_named_list,
                   selected = "DM_ask")
  })

  output$res <- renderPrint({
    names(which(quote_type_named_reac$x == input$group_quote_type))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks, maybe I wasn't completely clear. I need the values to remain the same, as they are important for the logic of my app. I do still need to retrieve the name the specific selected choice (to display in a chart title). Basically I need to have choices for app functionality, and names for display/GUI work, and this outside of the selectizeInput.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, you cannot access the label like the value with `input$foo` but you can store the choices and use them elsewhere. Is the edit answering your q ?

Comment: Does the purpose, tx.